# How does the Mobility stat work?

Tags: battle-inf

While playing the game (located here: `http://104.236.7.29:3001/`) I noticed that many items have a stat called "Mobility".  The only options I can find details on are mentioned in the Help tab:

> HP
>   HP Max
>   Attack
>   Defense
>   Dexterity
>   Aura
>   Defensive Aura

What is Mobility, and what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Swifty [Tower Level 5] : On the Help page, why is Mobility called Dexterity?
>
> Kaliad [Tower Level 5] : it needs updating
>
> Dexterity: This affects physical damage and dodge chance, with a maximum dodge chance of 25% and a minimum of 1%

Several people in chat said that Mobility affects dodge chance and chance to critically hit, which is probably the physical damage mentioned in Dexterity's description, but I hung around until Kaliad (the developer) weighed in to get an official source for you.